# Spring Cloud Stream. Azure EventHubs multiple input channels

Tags: spring, azure, kotlin, spring-cloud-stream, azure-eventhub

I am having problem customizing input channel name when using spring cloud stream azure event hub binder

[spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder/1.2.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/spring-cloud-azure-eventhubs-stream-binder/1.2.6)

**When I use Sink interface provided by spring cloud like this**:

```
@EnableBinding(Sink::class)
internal class SomeListener{

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    fun listener(
        message: GenericMessage<MyMessage>
    ) {
        logger.trace("Got message")
    }
}
```

with application properties like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      eventhub:
        connection-string: ...
        checkpoint-access-key: ...
        checkpoint-storage-account: ...
    stream:
      eventhub:
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              checkpoint-mode: BATCH
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: test
          group: $Default
          binder: eventhub
```

**I can receive messages without any problems**.

**But when I want to use custom channel like this:**

```
internal interface CustomSink {

    @Output(INPUT)
    fun input(): SubscribableChannel

    companion object {
        const val INPUT = "custom-input"
    }
}

@EnableBinding(CustomSink::class)
internal class SomeEventSinkListener{

    @StreamListener(CustomSink.INPUT)
    fun listener(
        message: GenericMessage<MyMessage>
    ) {
        logger.trace("Got message")
    }
}
```

and properties like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      eventhub:
        connection-string: <secret>
        checkpoint-access-key: <secret>
        checkpoint-storage-account: <secret>
    stream:
      eventhub:
        bindings:
          custom-input:
            consumer:
              checkpoint-mode: BATCH
      bindings:
        custom-input:
          destination: test
          group: $Default
          binder: eventhub
```

**I did not receive any messages**.
The only think changed is channel name. I don't know what is wrong. I can customize output channel name without problem but input channels work only if I use Sink interface Binding. I would like to listen on two different destinations in future that's why I need to custom input channels.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same question and also can't find the info in documentation.